# FFT of a fluctuating pressure using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am trying to do a FFT for a pressure variation that varies with time. However, since I am new to FFT analysis, I am not sure what I have done is correct. Any advice will be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from numpy import fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pressure_data = np.loadtxt('p.dat')
t, p = pressure_data[:,0], pressure_data[:,1]

number = len(p)
sample_period = 1.0/2000

f_coeffs = np.fft.fft(p)/number
f_coeffs_abs = np.absolute(f_coeffs)
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(number, sample_period)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(freq, f_coeffs_abs)
plt.show()
```

The `p.dat` file is something like this

```
0.0005      -2047.41878324
0.001      -1709.80828161
0.0015      -2158.61672106
0.002      -3766.56591721
```

where the first column is time and the second one is pressure

Comment: StackOverflow is meant to be a question and answer site.  You're not asking a real question here, but instead are asking for a code review.

Comment: In answer to your question though: A good way to know whether your code is working is to run it on some test data, *i.e.*, data where you know the expected result. This approach will work much better and catch many more problems than just looking at your code.  If you do this and don't get the result you expect, and can't figure out how to fix it, **then** it's probably a good time for a SO question.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example of a fft anaylsis is show here.

```
from scipy import fft
from numpy import arange, cos, pi, random
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplot, plot, ylabel, xlabel, title, grid, xlim, show

N = 2**9
F = 25
t = arange(N)/float(N)
x = cos(2*pi*t*F) + random.rand(len(t))*3
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,x)
ylabel('x []')
xlabel('t [seconds]')
title('A cosine wave')
grid()

subplot(2,1,2)
f = t*N
xf = fft(x)
plot(f,abs(xf))
title('Fourier transform of a cosine wave')
xlabel('xf []')
ylabel('xf []')
xlim([0,N])
grid()
show()
```

[image]

That should get you started. Notice the peaks at 25 and 475, thats the frequency we've defined as F

Comment: @tom10, could you elaborate?

Comment: @nagordon Thanks for you explanation with a working version of the code, albeit a slow in my response.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @nagordon's explanation: You can extract the peaks by doing something like:

```
xf = np.fft.fft(x)[:N//2] # it's reflected about middle so only take first half
...
threshold = 30.0
peaks = np.where(((xf[1:-1] - xf[:-2]) > threshold) & ((xf[1:-1] - xf[2:]) > threshold)) 
print([(i + 1, abs(xf[i + 1])) for i in peaks])
```